# Route all the traffic through my laptop (using Squid) wit Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, squid, routing

I have just installed Squid on my laptop and I am successfully blocking all the traffic that I want to block ( websites, protocols etc. ). But I would like to route all the traffic form my LAN ( have just 2 computers in it - and I use Dlink 502T router - I know, an old one). Any ideas how can I do this ?

I have found something like this on the web but this is for Linux http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/432

I have already thought about assigning my IP as a "default gateway" on other computers from my LAN but Squid uses port 3128. Would it work like this or should I change Squid port to 80 ? Will it work then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the browsers on the other computers to use your machine's squid port as the web proxy.

If you want to block other protocols or programs, you will need to setup a real router/gateway scenario, but there are several other pieces of software, and probably hardware, that you would need for that. The simplest scenario is just setting them to use your squid address as their default browser proxy.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
I know I can do that but I wanted to do something more "idiot proof" so that  e.g. kids for won't turn of the proxy in the browser settings or install another browser.

Comment: Your current network topology does not have your laptop between the users and their natural route. Anything you do to reroute them to your squid port will be a hack unless you redo the topology so that you are the default and only way out of the network.

Comment: ok, so hmm... that might be a stupid question but: what is the purpose of using squid then ? I mean in which situation (topology) ?

Comment: Squid is a cache system used to speed access to remote resources by keeping copies of frequently accessed things and being able to quickly serve them up locally instead of waiting for remote downloads. It is not an access-control system. It sounds like you actually want a firewall/filter of some kind.

Comment: yep, but squid has this functionality so why not? What other software would you recommend to use instead then ?

Comment: *Cars have windshield wipers but that doesn't make them a good tool to clean the windows of your house.* To get some good suggestions about the right tools for the job, you should probably open a new question here and explain your basic network situation and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Your home router should be setup to redirect request to port 80 and 443 to the squid server (or if your router can work on layer7 then HTTP and HTTPS requests) except when the request is coming from the squid server itself. Also you might want to block request to port 8080 as most proxies work on that port. Of course then you need a good router or maybe a Linux based router. One drawback of this setup is that if your laptop is off or the squid service is down, no one will access the internet.